# Send HTML form in email

Tags: php, html, forms, mailto

I would really need some help. I've created a simple HTML form with 2 select elements and 2 textareas.

When a user clicks on send button (--> input element type=submit), I would like all the selected items and entered text to show up inside an Outlook E-Mail, so that a user would only need to click send button inside the Outlook E-mail, to send it to a predefined address.

Is there a better way to send an E-Mail directly to an specific E-Mail address?

[Layout of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Po9wb.png)

Comment: What is an "Outlook E-Mail"? I only know "E-Mail messages".

Comment: If this is just about sending a simple email message, then why is this an issue? There are millions of examples for that. After the form submit you simply take the form values on the server side, create a message from it and send it. As easy as that.

Answer (score 0):

If your server supports PHP I strongly recommend using PHP to achieve this, for more, check this out-> http://www.freecontactform.com/email_form.php. This way you can check the input the user is typing before processing it any further. Without using php you can easily achieve it by using `mailto` method like:

```
<a href="mailto:EMAILADDRESS">
```